# Queries about multiple kernel in opencl

Tags: opencl

when I use multiple kernel in `opencl` such that result of first kernel `(K1)` execution is input to second kernel `(K2)` execution,so two questions are:

1. The event should be different for each kernel or should be same for
   each kernel?
2. The command queue should be different for each kernel or should be
   same for each kernel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a single command queue (assuming the kernels are executed on the same device).

Unless your command queue is created with **CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE**, you don't need to create events in the scenario you describe: kernels are executed in the order they are enqueued.

For an out-of-order command queue, you should get an event from the first **clEnqueueNDRangeKernel**, and pass it as dependency to the second one. Remember to release the events with **clReleaseEvent**.

Comment: I mean in your case you just need one command queue (created with no options), and no event.

Comment: can i use one kernel for some cores and another kernel for remaining cores simultaneously on  same GPU

Comment: @reva It's called device fission and yes, it is supported by the OpenCL framework, but I am not aware of any GPU which currently supports this feature (CPU's do). This is because current GPU's are not preemptive and only run one task at a time (ever noticed how your screen froze if your kernel, no matter how simple, entered an infinite loop?). Future GPU's should have this feature.